# TableViewController editingStyle and insertion

Tags: iphone, uitableview

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

I need both insertion and deletion options so...

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addItem:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Thats all good so far. I am done programming with "deletion" but having trouble with "insertion"

```
   - (void)addItem:sender {
}
```

What do I add inside this addItem to start "Editing mode" and change my EditingStyle to UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert? What the hell is that iteminputcontroller as seen in the apple library? There's no explanation on that and help is vague online :(

Comment: Do you want the `delete` and `insertion` separately on a single `UIViewTable` ?

Comment: yep, there are separate. leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem. the buttons are added but I cant figure how to program the insertion button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke setEditing function of your `tableView` inside your `addItem` method.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
```

Should be like below.

```
- (void)addItem:sender {
   [myTableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` from your `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
     - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if(someCondtion){
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }
}
```

Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       //put code to handle deletion
       [myTableView reloadData];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
       //put code to handle insertion
       [myTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of built in functions, first set:

```
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;
```

And add to your

```
- (void)addItem:sender {
     [tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Then, just override this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {
       // If user deletes
       if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
       {
          //DELETE THE KEY FROM YOUR DATASOURCE AND THEN:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; //NICE EFFECT
       }
       else if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
       {
           //ADD THE KEY TO YOUR DATASOURCE AND THEN:
           [tableView reloadData]; //THIS JUST RELOADS THE TABLE WITH YOUR DATASOURCE UPDATED       
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much value in having a **+** button, if it will act like an 'Edit' button... right? So, your `addItem:` method should implement code for displaying a new view, i.e. present a view controller for entering the details of the item to add. (I'm basing this example from Apple's sample code):

```
- (void)addItem:(id)sender {
    // ItemInputController is a view controller used to display textFields, etc.
    // whatever you need for your new item... You have to write it, name it however you want
    ItemInputController *itemInputController = [[ItemInputController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:itemInputController];

    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

    [navigationController release];
    [itemInputController release];

}
```

Otherwise, to use `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`, you need to actually configure a cell with `editingStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` (for example, the last cell in your table). You go into editing mode by tapping the 'Edit' button. When the user taps on your 'add item' cell, you would call the same code as in the `addItem:` method as above.

I hope this clears things up for you.